# Finding a CFG for this Language

Tags: computer-science, context-free-grammar

Prove that the following Language is context-free and provide a CFG.
$L=\{a^i b^j a^i b^{j+1} \mid \text{$i, j$ ∈ N}\}$ 
I have already proven that the language is context-free by using the Pumping-Lemma:

- Let $n$ be the Pumping-Lemma-Number, $z$ be a word in the language and
  $\lvert z \rvert \geq n$.
- Let $uvwxy$ represent $z$.
- Let $u$ and $w$ represent $a^i$.
- Let $v$ and $x$ represent $b^j$.
- Let $y$ represent $b$.
- Then $uv^2wx^2y$ is still in the language.

But I just cannot think of a grammar that would produce this language. Did I make a mistake in my proof?

Comment: Just because the language satisfies the pumping lemma, doesn't mean it's context free. The pumping lemma can only disprove the property. In this case it seems intuitively clear that a pushdown automaton cannot recognize this language. I'm not sure how to prove it now.

Comment: It is well known that $L = \{ a^{i}a^{i} \mid i \in N\}$ is certainly a context-free language -- it is very close to the language for matching parentheses. Perhaps the answers lies in the non-symmetric or overlapping symmetric nature of the open-close relationships between the $a$ and $b$ terms. We know that $L = \{ a^{i}b^{i}c^{i} \mid i \in N\}$ is also context-sensitive and not context-free.